# Android Native Datepicker crashes in Samsung S4 device

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, android-datepicker

I have created an application in phonegap. In all the device the DatePicker(Phonegap Datepicker plugin) is working fine, except Samsung S4 device.
I am getting the error java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "JAN" .
Please help me on this.

Thanks
Tiru

Comment: Could you share a snippet of your datepicker code?

Comment: Also the cordova/Phonegap version you're using.

Comment: @Tiru have u found the solution? My app hangs after picking the date from date picker.

Comment: @QadirHussain I have answered, see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the html file I changed the input type from Date/time to text then after its working fine.